# Cookie disappears on page refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using jQuery.cookie set cookies, however if I refresh the page or open a new page,sometimes, the cookie is lost. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.cookie('sid', 'sessionid', {expires: 30, path: '/', domain: 'xici.net'});
```

discussion:
expires: 30  means 30 days, it set by jQuery.cookie library scurse code.

Comment: Are you trying to make a cross domain cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Add that 30 min value to the current time to specify that exipre this cookie in  **30 minutes in the future**.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var myCookieValue = $.cookie('myCookie');
jQuery.cookie('myCookie', null);
jQuery.cookie('sid', 'sessionid', {expires: date, path: '/', domain: 'xici.net'});
```

Comment: Doesn't mean 30 days? From documentation: ***Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then: ***: $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

Comment: If you give number,it expires in that many days,what if you want to pass minutes ??

Comment: using your solution. You pass a `Date` object. I initially posted this question to GreailsGuy, and I thought that you also say that "30 is very much in the past".

Comment: @Johnツ No not at all :) I did'nt find any meaning in the statement "30 is very much in the past"  :P

Answer (score 1):

@rainweb

Try using the latest jQuery-cookie plugin and jQuery library. You are doing everything right.

Anyway to get a link to the site in question to debug it further?

Also See: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

@suresh atta

> If you give number,it expires in that many days,what if you want to pass minutes ??

By default, setting an integer value to "expires:" will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date object. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie and gets deleted once the browsers session ends or page is closed. You cannot set an expiration time of minutes, just days or by session.

Comment: \n thks! I'm using the latest jQuery-cookie plugin ,but it's also happened.  not everytime, but sometimes happened.

Comment: Could you explain more details about 'the browsers session ends'?