# Server cookies lost on page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch

I tried fetch to call api and passing credentials "`include`" to header which set cookies from server initially but on page refresh cookies got lost.

```
public post = async (payload:any, endpoint: string):Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(${config.baseUrl}${endpoint})

            const URL = ${config.baseUrl}${endpoint};
            fetch(URL, {
                credentials: 'include',
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
                headers: new Headers({
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then((data:any) => {
                console.log("data", data)
                const responsePayload = {
                    statusCode: data.status,
                    data: data
                };
                resolve(responsePayload);
            })
            .catch((error:any) => {
                if (error.response === undefined) {
                    const errorpayload = {
                        statusCode: 503,
                        title: 'network error occured',
                        parameter: 'Network Error',
                    };
                    reject(errorpayload);
                } else {
                    const errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    const errorPayload = {
                        statusCode: error.response.status,
                        data: error.response.data.errors,
                    };
                    reject(errorPayload);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: fetch already returns a promise, why is your function wrapped in promise?

Comment: also where is it in your code that you are refreshing your page?

Comment: this might help your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714962/cookie-disappears-on-page-refresh I can't give you more information without seeing the entire context of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better read cookies on login and store it to loaclstorage and from there you can use it the way you want.